# Heartbeat status NiFi flow

Tags: apache-nifi

I want to create a scheduled heartbeat status process in a websocket flow. This is the flow I'm trying to achieve. Connect to websocket -> first message has heartbeat status interval -> parse the interval value -> start scheduled processor to send a heartbeat status through websocket connection -> in the same websocket connection, wait for other message to come through that will be parsed.

I have a flow that currently looks like this
[image]

The **heartbeat statusing** process group looks like this.
[image]

1. Does this look right?
2. How should the retry flow file in the heartbeat statusing look? It doesn't seem to be working. it keeps queuing retries, but never goes through the retries_exceeded relationship.
3. will the heartbeat statusing process group run in its own thread?
4. how can I pass the websocket session to the heartbeat statusing process group?

Comment: Not clear why it's so complicated. Why it's not just scheduled putsocket? Ps: every processor in nifi executed in random thread from thread pool.

Comment: the interval needs to be dynamically set based on the input that gets passed into the processor.